# Basic Javascript Countdown

Tags: javascript, intervals, countdown

Good day fellow developers. Please entertain what must seem like a very simple question: I have a basic countdown with the intent of counting down to 5 and loops continually.

```
var countDownDiv = document.getElementById('countDown');
window.setInterval(intervalCountDown, 1000);
function intervalCountDown() {
  var counter = 5;
  countDownDiv.innerHTML = counter--;
}
```

The problem is that it's not counting down, for what reason I don't know. Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ajikanfan/4tpcdtdj/) I've created if that helps.

Comment: you redefine your counter every time `countDown` called.

Comment: yep, you always reset your countdown

Comment: initialize your counter outside the function

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b0opb3ms/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You redefine your counter every time countDown called.
To prevent this, you should define variable in outer scope.

```js
var countDownDiv = document.getElementById('countDown');
window.setInterval(intervalCountDown, 1000);
var counter = 5;
function intervalCountDown() {
  countDownDiv.innerHTML = counter--;
}
```

```html
<span id="countDown"></span>
```

You can also create something more reusable:

```js
    function countDown(from, time, el) {
      el.innerHTML = from;
      var i = setInterval(tick, time);
      function tick() {
        el.innerHTML = --from;
        if (from <= 0) clearInterval(i);
      }
    }

countDown(100, 1000, document.getElementById('c1'));
countDown(10, 5000, document.getElementById('c2'));
```

```html
<span id="c1"></span><hr/>
<span id="c2"></span>
```

Comment: This answer was demonstration for my comment above. I'll add details

Comment: Wow, great code! Thank you for the answer. Used `setInterval(function, 6000);` to repeat function and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your **var counter** outside the **function intervalCountDown()**

```
var countDownDiv = document.getElementById('countDown');
window.setInterval(intervalCountDown, 1000);
  var counter = 5;
function intervalCountDown() {
  countDownDiv.innerHTML = counter--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your counter outside the function.

```
var countDownDiv = document.getElementById('countDown');
window.setInterval(intervalCountDown, 1000);
var counter = 5;
function intervalCountDown() {

  countDownDiv.innerHTML = counter--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a new `counter` variable each tick. Move `counter` out of the tick function:

```js
var countDownDiv = document.getElementById('countDown');
var counter = 5;
window.setInterval(intervalCountDown, 1000);

function intervalCountDown() {
  countDownDiv.innerHTML = counter--;
}
```

```html
<div id="countDown"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring the counter variable in every turn. Fix: http://jsfiddle.net/4tpcdtdj/1/

```
var countDownDiv = document.getElementById('countDown');
var counter = 5;
var countInterval = setInterval(intervalCountDown, 1000);

function intervalCountDown() {
  if (counter <= -1) {
    clearInterval(countInterval);
    return;
  }

  countDownDiv.textContent = counter--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You redefining counter variable with value 5.
You can use closure as below

```
var countDownDiv = document.getElementById('countDown');
window.setInterval(intervalCountDown(), 1000);
function intervalCountDown() {
  var counter = 5;
  return function(){
    countDownDiv.innerHTML = counter--;
    if(counter==0) // Re-initiate counter
      counter = 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable counter declared in Locally so again and again assign the same value counter = 5. That is the problem below display my correction

```
var bingoDiv = document.getElementById('bingo');
window.setInterval(intervalBingo, 5000);

function intervalBingo() {
  var newNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) + 1;
  bingoDiv.innerHTML = newNum;
}
// basic countdown
var countDownDiv = document.getElementById('countDown');
window.setInterval(intervalCountDown, 1000);
var counter = 5;
function intervalCountDown() {

    if (counter == 0) {
     counter =5;
   }
  countDownDiv.innerHTML = counter--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// number randomizer
var bingoDiv = document.getElementById('bingo');
var counter = 5;
var counter_interval = false;
window.setInterval(intervalBingo, 5000);
function intervalBingo() {
  var newNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) + 1;
  counter = 5;
  bingoDiv.innerHTML = newNum;
  clearInterval(counter_interval);
  countDownDiv.innerHTML = counter--;
  counter_interval = window.setInterval(intervalCountDown, 1000);
}
// basic countdown
var countDownDiv = document.getElementById('countDown');
function intervalCountDown() {
  countDownDiv.innerHTML = counter--;
}
```

```html
<div id="bingo"></div>
<hr>
<div id="countDown"></div>
```

i thing like this, you can try this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var num = document.getElementById("countDown");//Get value from div.
var counter = 5; //Declaring counter value.
num.innerHTML = counter;//assigning counter value to num variable
function deg(){
counter--;//decrementing counter value.
num.innerHTML = counter;//getting output in div using innerHTML
if(counter <= 0){ //if couter value reaches or goes below 0 then stop     
// decrementing of counter value. 
window.clearInterval(st);
}
}
var st = window.setInterval(deg,1000);
```